# Recommendation for a platform to make a web classroom without install a software?

Tags: php, html, web, latex, class-relationship

I am making some search to do a web classroom online with :

- responsive (so without Flash)
- Without install a software
- chat
- LaTex
- waiting line
- one student at a time
- Video conference
- White board

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try WebRTC.

WebRTC is an open framework for the web that enables Real Time Communications in the browser. It includes the fundamental building blocks for high-quality communications on the web, such as network, audio and video components used in voice and video chat applications.

For more information  about WebRTC, visit [link](https://webrtc.org/)

Try webrtc [samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/)

Try the [HTML5 Rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

Comment: seems to be great but can we put a white board with WebRTC?

Comment: @user2507113, yes, with WebRTC you can. it will be possible with RTCDataChannel